# Calculating an average in a data frame based on locations from separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame set up like so:

```
N1 <- c(1,2,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,8,9)
Start <- c("","Start","","","","","","","Start","","","","Start","","","","")
Stop <- c("","","","","Stop","","","","","","Stop","","","","Stop","","")
```

With N1 being my data of interest. I would like to calculate the mean of a string of numbers based on the "Start" and "Stop" locations in the next two columns.

The strings as defined by "Start" and "Stop" would look like so:

```
2,4,3,2 
4,3,4
4,5,6
```

So my final result should be 3 means:

```
    2.75,3.6,5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
mapply(function(start, stop){
          mean(N1[start:stop])
       }, 
       start=which(Start!=""), 
       stop=which(Stop!=""))

#[1] 2.750000 3.666667 5.000000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(data.table) # need latest 1.9.5+

# set up data to have all 1's column for the period we're interested in and 0 otherwise
d = data.table(N1, event = cumsum((Start != "") - c(0, head(Stop != "", -1))))

d[, mean(N1), by = .(event, rleid(event))][event == 1, V1]
#[1] 2.750000 3.666667 5.000000

# or equivalently
d[, .(event[1], mean(N1)), by = rleid(event)][V1 == 1, V2]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try `rollapply`

```
library(zoo)
x <- sort(c(which(Stop != ""), which(Start != ""))) # indices of Start and Stop
rollapply(x, 2, FUN = function(y) mean(N1[y[1]:y[2]]), by=2)
[1] 2.750000 3.666667 5.000000
```